# Trouble creating an instance of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

All, 
I have a bar button item on my ViewController. I have set a computed property to will turn the BarButton off. I want to be able to set this from another class.

Here is my code in the view controller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var PayButton : Int {
        didSet {

                navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        self.PayButton = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
```

When it try and create an instance on the view controller (so I can set the PayButton integer)

```
let test = ViewController()
```

I get an error saying

> Missing Argument for parameter 'coder' in call

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have implemented the  required initializer in ViewController class.

There are two solutions

1. Add a default initializer

   init() {
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
     }
2. Remove the required initializer.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var PayButton : Int {
    didSet {

            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

init() {

    self.PayButton = 0
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
  }

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self.PayButton = 0
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for the parameter 'coder', because you have it in the `required init`.

To use your code as it stands, you would need to initialise with:

```
let test = ViewController(coder: NSCoder)
```

There are several ways to get around this.  The easiest would be to remove the required initialiser.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var PayButton : Int = 0 {
        didSet {

            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }
}
```

and then implement with

```
let test = ViewController()
test.PayButton = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This is the required initializer:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

This is the super initializer:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

This is your convenience initializer where you can pass the size the view you want to create

```
convenience init(view: UIView){
    self.init(frame: view.frame)
}
```

This is your convenience initializer where the view is initialized with a value pre defined:

```
convenience init(){
    self.init(frame: CGRectZero) //Put you predefined value here
}
```